# Best way to rename an auto-generated report in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

How do you assign a name to a MS Access report created via CreateReport?

Code creates a dynamic report then adds controls to the report. Last, I want to name/save the report as "Student_Scores_Report01" but it appears that CreateReport auto-generates the name for the report as Report1, Report2, etc. I've run into issues where Access creates a "Report1" but it doesn't actually exist, causing the whole project to be corrupted. This is my best guess at working around this but it seems inefficient:

```
Dim rpt as Report
Set rpt = CreateReport
Dim ReptNmTemp as String
ReptNmTemp = rpt.name
DoCmd.Save acReport, rpt.Name
DoCmd.Close acReport, rpt.Name
DoCmd.Rename "Student_Scores_Report01", acReport, ReptNmTemp
For Each rpt02 In CurrentProject.AllReports
If rpt02.Name = ReptNmTemp Then
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acReport, ReptNmTemp
End If
Next
```

The For...each loop deletes the auto-generated report and avoids the corruption problem. But is there a better way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping you could `On Error Resume Next` or some other error handler.

```
Dim rpt as Report
Dim ReptNmTemp as String
Set rpt = CreateReport
ReptNmTemp = rpt.name
DoCmd.Save acReport, ReptNmTemp
DoCmd.Close acReport, ReptNmTemp, acSaveYes
DoCmd.Rename "Student_Scores_Report01", acReport, ReptNmTemp
On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.DeleteObject acReport, ReptNmTemp
```

Or use acDefault, which is actually a default parameter for both Save and Close, which means if parameter is not provided, acDefault will be used.

```
Dim rpt as Report
Set rpt = CreateReport
DoCmd.Save , "Student_Scores_Report01"
DoCmd.Close , , acSaveYes
```

Comment: Good point, that's a bit more efficient---but the bigger question for me is still "after you create a report, how do you name it?" It seems that CreateReport generates a the default Access report, same as when you click buttons to create a report in Design view or whatever. Is it possible that there's no direct way to assign a name to that report via VBA?

Comment: @DrL, see revised answer.

Comment: there it is, tested and works in two lines instead of 10. Thank you